# Passing (ID) argument from aspx page to javascript function which updates ID somewhere else on the page

Tags: javascript, parameters, click

So imagine I have a table which is a list of videos, with associated descriptions and links. On the page there is only ever one video shown. When a link is clicked, I want that click to take the ID of the corresponding video and pass it to the video player div, updating whatever video is displayed, ready for play.

VidName | Description | Watch
...and repeat...generated from a foreach in C#

I believe I will need to use

```
.bind( 'click', [eventData,] handler(eventObject) )
```

but I am not sure what to put for the second argument - I know I want the ID, but from where? Does the 'Watch' text HAVE to made into a (submit) button or something?

Intinctively I think this is quite simple...sorry for the dumb question if it is one! :)

Comment: It is not a dumb question, we all have to start somewhere to learn this stuff :) It would be very useful if you supplied your html code or snippet of it as a reference for the answers

Answer (score 0):

so why dont you just use the onclick event on the link?

```
<a id="1" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="DoSomething(this.id)">Simple's</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way i usually do it is something like this:

```
<sometag data-id="id-for-the-data"></sometag>

<script>

  function onSometagClick() {
     $(this).prop('data-id'); // read the id so we can us it
  }

  $(function(){
     $(document.body).delegate('sometag','click',onSometagClick); //handle clicks on all 'sometag' ellements
});
</script>
```

If you want a less generic answer, please supply some markup :)

The reason i don't use the id attribute is threefold.

1: to separate the markup/DOM from the actual data

2: id attributes are not allowed to start with a number, and my data id's are almost always numbers from a database somewhere.

3: if i need to reference the same data more than once on a page the id attribute is no good since it needs to be unique